# can't search data in database

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2, sql-like

Hey I am new in coding and I have a problem to search the data in database from python. Can anyone tell what's the problem with my code.This query gives me error

```
cursor.execute("select * from pharmacy where " + self.search_var.get() + " LIKE " + str(self.searchtxt_var.get())+"%")
```

Here is the error:

```
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at end of input
LINE 1: select * from pharmacy where ref_no LIKE 123%
                                                    ^
```

Comment: Use parameters, so you don't ever have problems like this.

Comment: and if you want to continue going your way,use quotes select * from pharmacy where ref_no LIKE '123%'

Comment: You should be surrounding the value for LIKE clause with quotes :
`cursor.execute("select * from pharmacy where " + self.search_var.get() + " LIKE '" + str(self.searchtxt_var.get())+"%'")` Please Note the single quotes added in there.

Comment: See here [psycopg2 parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries), in particular "Warning
Never, never, NEVER use Python string concatenation (+) or string parameters interpolation (%) to pass variables to a SQL query string. Not even at gunpoint. "